# How to find current visible viewController in iOS

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

We know , if your viewController have been contain UINavigationController ,

you can find your current visible view controller by 'self.navigationController.visibleViewController' .

But I you present a view controller , how to find current visible controller ?

### For Example :

```
code one :
------
AVClr *avclr = [[AVClr alloc]init] ;
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate ;
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = avclr ;
[avclr presentViewController:loginNavClr animated:YES completion:nil] ;
```

---> now , display `avclr`

```
code two:
------
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate ;
UIViewController *currentVisibleViewController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController ;
BVClr *bvclr = [[BVClr alloc]init] ;
[currentVisibleViewController presentViewController:bvclr animated:YES completion:nil] ;
```

---> now , display `bvclr`

```
code three:
------
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate ;
UIViewController *currentVisibleViewController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController ;
CVClr *cvclr = [[CVClr alloc]init] ;
[currentVisibleViewController presentViewController:cvclr animated:YES completion:nil] ;
```

---> Error , can not display `cvclr` , because `avclr` is a rootViewController and `avclr` present `bvclr` , so display `bvclr` .

### Question:

But we know ,code three in another .m file , so we don't know who is the rootViewController . so If I present `cvclr` , the result is unexpect !

In the circumstances ，how to display `cvclr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(UIViewController *)getVisibleViewController : (UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    UIViewController *rootVC = rootViewController;
    if (rootVC == nil)
    {
        rootVC = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
    }

    if ([rootVC presentedViewController] == nil)
    {
        return rootVC;
    }

    if ([rootVC presentedViewController] != nil)
    {
        if ([[rootVC presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:UINavigationController.self]) {
            UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[rootVC presentedViewController];
            return [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
        }
        return [self getVisibleViewController : [rootVC presentedViewController]];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Did it help? I have not tested it but written code here only.. So correct if some syntax are wrong.. But you will get basic idea..

Answer (score 1):

to find current top view controller i used this method

```
- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController
{
   UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
   while (topVC.presentedViewController)
   {
     topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
   }
   if ([topVC isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
      return [(UINavigationController *)topVC topViewController];
   }
  return topVC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting the next screen from that class then you don't need to fetch top view controller from `UIWindow`
Simply use this..

```
 -----------------
AVClr *avclr = [[AVClr alloc]init];
[self presentViewController: avclr animated:YES completion:nil] ;

------------------------------


BVClr *bvclr = [[BVClr alloc]init] ;
[self.presentingViewControler presentViewController:bvclr animated:YES completion:nil] ;

------------------


CVClr *cvclr = [[CVClr alloc]init] ;
[self.presentingViewControler presentViewController:cvclr animated:YES completion:nil] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also check `UITabbarViewContoller` :

```
-(UIViewController *) getVisibleViewContoller {
    UIViewController *rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.rootViewController;
    if (!rootViewController) {
        return nil;
    }
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {
        UITabBarController *tabbarVC = (UITabBarController *) rootViewController;
        UIViewController *selectedVC = tabbarVC.selectedViewController;
        if (selectedVC) {
            if (![selectedVC isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
                return selectedVC;
            }
            rootViewController = selectedVC;
        }
    }
    if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationVC = (UINavigationController *) rootViewController;
        if (navigationVC.topViewController) {
            return navigationVC.topViewController;
        }
        return navigationVC.viewControllers.lastObject;
    }
    return rootViewController;
}
```